# Redux select a property from an array of objects using useSelector

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-redux, javascript-objects

I am trying to access a value from an array of objects in my Redux store

Redux actions:

```
export const EMAIL = 'EMAIL'
export const email = (email) => {
    return {type: EMAIL, email: email}
}
```

Redux reducer:

```
    import { EMAIL} from '../actions/email'
    const initialState = {
        email : [ 
            {
            "id": 1595174674588,
            "val": "john@gmail.com",
            },
           {
            "id": 1595174746874,
            "val": "susan@gmail.com",
            },
        
        ]
    }
    const emailReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
        switch(action.type){
            case EMAIL:
                    return  {...state, email: state.email.concat(action.email)}
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
export default emailReducer
```

App.js

```
import emailReducer from './Store/reducers/email'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    emails: emailReducer,  
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer, enhancer)

const App = () => {
  return(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RecipieNavigation/>
    </Provider>
    
  )
}
```

The component I am trying to access the `email` from:

```
const AddScreen = () => {
    const email = useSelector(state => state.emails.email.val)
    const valid =  email.length === 0 
            ? false
            : true
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{valid===true? 'Email Valid': 'No email'}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I am trying to obtain the length of the `email` from `Redux-reducer` however I'm getting the error `undefined is not an object evaluating (email.val.length)` I am trying to see if there is an email the `TextInput` is valid or if no email not Valid. I would really appreciate it from the bottom of my heart if someone could help me with figuring this out. Thank you in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you exported your reducer since its not shown, but assuming you did:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  emails: emailReducer
});
```

```
const initialState = {
    email : [ 
        {
        "id": 1595174674588,
        "val": "john@gmail.com",
        },
       {
        "id": 1595174746874,
        "val": "susan@gmail.com",
        },
    
    ]
}
```

Based on the above you are passing the following object structure to emails:

```
emails: {email: [{id,val},{id,val}]}
```

But the way you call it:

```
 const email = useSelector(state => state.emails.email.val)
```

Resembles an object structure like:

```
emails: {email: {val}}
```

What you instead want (assuming you're trying to map each email val) is:

```
const email = useSelector(state => state.emails.email.map(ele => ele.val))
```

Comment: Is there a better way than mapping because the state is initially empty and when I add values it looks like the initial state I showed in the question so it actually empty at first so mapping won't be ideal . I just want to check if there are objects in the array and return true so i can validate is that possible . I don't really want the values per say but just to check that the email array isn't empty

Comment: Then just set it straight "useSelector(state => state.emails.email)" and use "email.length" as a conditional wherever you need to check if objects are in the array.